# Terraform Error creating Lambda function: ResourceConflictException with the resource just created by Terraform apply

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am deploying a Lambda function in each AWS Region of our account and encountering weird issue where the Apply is failing with the following error message for some of the AWS Regions

**Error while Terraform Apply**

```
Error: Error creating Lambda function: ResourceConflictException: Function already exist: log-forwarder
{
  RespMetadata: {
    StatusCode: 409,
    RequestID: "8cfd7260-7c4a-42d2-98c6-6619c7b2804f"
  },
  Message_: "Function already exist: log-forwarder",
  Type: "User"
}
```

The above Lambda function has just been created by same Terraform Apply that is failing.

The terraform plan and init doesn't throw any errors about having TF config issues.

Both plan and init runs successfully.

Below is my directory structure

```
.
├── log_forwarder.tf
├── log_forwarder_lambdas
│   └── main.tf
└── providers.tf
```

Below is my `providers.tf` file

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-east-1"
  version = "3.9.0"
}
provider "aws" {
  alias   = "us-east-2"
  region  = "us-east-2"
  version = "3.9.0"
}
provider "aws" {
  alias   = "us-west-2"
  region  = "us-west-2"
  version = "3.9.0"
}  
provider "aws" {
  alias   = "us-west-1"
  region  = "us-west-1"
  version = "3.9.0"
}
provider "aws" {
  alias   = "ca-central-1"
  region  = "ca-central-1"
  version = "3.9.0"
}


... with all the AWS Regions.
```

Below is the tf config of `log_forwarder.tf`

```
terraform {
  required_version = "0.12.25"

  backend "s3" {
    All the backend Config
  }
}


resource "aws_iam_role" "log_forwarder" {
  name = "LogForwarder"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": ["lambda.amazonaws.com"]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "log_forwarder" {
  name = "LogForwarder"
  role = aws_iam_role.log_forwarder.id

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "lambda:ListTags",
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:logs:*",
        "arn:aws:lambda:*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
        {
    "Sid": "AWSDatadogPermissionsForCloudtrail",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": ["s3:ListBucket", "s3:GetBucketLocation", "s3:GetObject", "s3:ListObjects"],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::BucketName",
        "arn:aws:s3:::BucketName/*"
    ]
}

  ]
}
EOF
}


module "DDLogForwarderUSEast1" {
  source                = "./log_forwarder_lambdas"
  dd_log_forwarder_role = aws_iam_role.log_forwarder.arn
  region                = "us-east-1"

}

module "DDLogForwarderUSEast2" {
  source                = "./log_forwarder_lambdas"
  dd_log_forwarder_role = aws_iam_role.log_forwarder.arn
  providers             = { aws = aws.us-east-2 }
  region                = "us-east-2"
}

module "DDLogForwarderUSWest1" {
  source                = "./log_forwarder_lambdas"
  dd_log_forwarder_role = aws_iam_role.log_forwarder.arn
  providers             = { aws = aws.us-west-1 }
  region                = "us-west-1"
}

module "DDLogForwarderUSWest2" {
  source                = "./log_forwarder_lambdas"
  dd_log_forwarder_role = aws_iam_role.log_forwarder.arn
  region                = "us-west-2"
  providers             = { aws = aws.us-west-2 }
}

module "DDLogForwarderAPEast1" {
  source                = "./log_forwarder_lambdas"
  dd_log_forwarder_role = aws_iam_role.log_forwarder.arn
  providers             = { aws = aws.ap-east-1 }
  region                = "ap-east-1"
}

module "DDLogForwarderAPSouth1" {
  source                = "./log_forwarder_lambdas"
  dd_log_forwarder_role = aws_iam_role.log_forwarder.arn
  region                = "ap-south-1"
  providers             = { aws = aws.ap-south-1 }
}

... All AWS Regions with different providers
```

TF Config of `log_forwarder_lambdas/main.tf`

```
variable "region" {}

variable "account_id" {
  default = "AWS Account Id"
}

variable "dd_log_forwarder_role" {}

variable "exclude_at_match" {
  default = "([A-Z]* RequestId: .*)"
}

data "aws_s3_bucket" "cloudtrail_bucket" {
  count  = var.region == "us-west-2" ? 1 : 0
  bucket = "BucketName"
}


resource "aws_lambda_function" "log_forwarder" {
  filename      = "${path.cwd}/log_forwarder_lambdas/aws-dd-forwarder-3.16.3.zip"
  function_name = "log-forwarder"
  role          = var.dd_log_forwarder_role
  description   = "Gathers logs from targetted Cloudwatch Log Groups and sends them to DataDog"
  handler       = "lambda_function.lambda_handler"
  runtime       = "python3.7"
  timeout       = 600
  memory_size   = 1024
  layers        = ["arn:aws:lambda:${var.region}:464622532012:layer:Datadog-Python37:11"]


  environment {
    variables = {
      DD_ENHANCED_METRICS = false
      EXCLUDE_AT_MATCH    = var.exclude_at_match
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "log_forwarder" {
  name              = "/aws/lambda/${aws_lambda_function.log_forwarder.function_name}"
  retention_in_days = 90
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "cloudtrail_bucket" {
  count         = var.region == "us-west-2" ? 1 : 0
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromS3Bucket"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.log_forwarder.arn
  principal     = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = element(data.aws_s3_bucket.cloudtrail_bucket.*.arn, count.index)
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "cloudtrail_bucket_notification" {
  count  = var.region == "us-west-2" ? 1 : 0
  bucket = element(data.aws_s3_bucket.cloudtrail_bucket.*.id, count.index)


  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = aws_lambda_function.log_forwarder.arn
    events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
  }

  depends_on = [aws_lambda_permission.cloudtrail_bucket, aws_cloudwatch_log_group.log_forwarder]
}
```

I am using TF 0.12.25 in this case.

The things I have tried so far.

1. Remove the .terraform folder from the root module every time I run the Terraform init/plan/apply cycle
2. I have tried to refactor code as much as possible.
3. I am running the TF Plan/Apply cycle locally without any CI.

Answer (score 6):

At first glance it looks as though the Lambda function may not be in your Terraform state (for whatever reason). Have you changed backends / deleted data off your backend?

Run a `terraform show` and/or `terraform state show` and see if the conflicting Lambda function is in your state.
If it is not, but it already exists in AWS, you can import it.
See here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function#import

---

**Update:**

As per your coment, since the resource exists in AWS but not in the state, this is an expected error. (Terraform doesn't know the resource exists, therefore tries to create it; AWS knows it already exists, therefore returns an error.)

You have two choices:

- Delete the resource in AWS and run Terraform again; or
- Import the existing recource into Terraform (recomended).

Try something like:

```
terraform import module.DDLogForwarderUSEast1.aws_lambda_function.log-forwarder log-forwarder
```

(Make sure you have the correct provider/region set up if trying this for other regions!)

Comment: That was my initial thought process that somehow Lambda function is already exists in AWS and my TF is complaining about it. However I have double check the targeted regions but no success. I also spin up above infra pieces in completely separate AWS Account just for seperation but still the same error.

Comment: Define success? > However I have double check the targeted regions but no success.

Comment: What is the output of your `terraform show` then? Are the functions there, or not?

Comment: When I run the TF apply to above code , it starts creating all the necessary resources and in the end of the run fails with Resource Already exists error message. If I go to targeted region mentioned in the TF error, I can see that lambda function has been created by TF Apply cycle ( few mins ago ). However `terraform state list` doesn't have any resource like that. I have visually inspect the terraform state in s3 backend and its also missing the resources that just created by TF apply cycle.

Comment: I deleted the resource in AWS, run the script successfully.  But the next time I push a change, my pipeline throws the exact same error.  I have to delete the lambda every time I want to push a change. @JeffHemmen do you have any pointers?

Comment: Run `terraform state list` to see whether the resource is in the state or not. That'll help you figure out wheere the error is (Terraform writing to state at all, or realising the one in the state matches the one deployed).

Answer (score 0):

We are experiencing exactly the same issue and I can 100% confirm it is caused by terraform run. It does create a resource but does not include in its own state. It cannot be reproduced every time unfortunately. So far we do not have any fix. Were you managed to find a root cause ? It looks very much a like a bug. For your information we actually upgraded module version due to this but it did not help, currently we are runnig on:

tf version: 1.0.5
tf module lambda: 4.8